# Select and update table then stop selecting when value is zero

Tags: php, mysql

I.e amount to pay more than one client for same type of products is $20,000. 
Client One $12,000,
Client Two $3,000,
Client Two $5,000.
Which to total is $20,000.

I want when buyer clicks to purchase for a product and they are available,

1. Select and update table until buyer amount to pay gets to zero then stop.
2. Count number of rows of those he should pay and update his row.

I have tried

```
$qry=mysqli_query($link,"Select sum(selleramount) from sellertable Where buyer product>0");
$asum=$row[0];
($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ry));
foreach ($qry as $row) {
    $balance=$buyeramount-$asum;
    mysqli_query($link,"insert into buyertable (amount,seller_id,) values ('$amount_to_payseller','$sellertopayid')");
    mysqli_query($link,"update sellertable set seller amount='$balance'");
}
```

I have tried but its not working out. I have the idea but how to go about what I want I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have your data to test it properly, but the Transaction method may work here. Example!

```
$qry=mysqli_query($link,"Select sum(selleramount) from sellertable Where buyer product>0");
$asum=$row[0];
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ry));
foreach ($qry as $row) {
    $balance=$buyeramount-$asum;
    mysqli_query($link,"insert into buyertable (amount,seller_id,) values ('$amount_to_payseller','$sellertopayid')");
    mysqli_query($link,"update sellertable set seller amount='$balance'");
}
$mysqli->commit();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Please what will the solution above is expected to do.

Comment: In effect a Transaction and commit will basically pend the transaction and on completion, commit by moving the end of record pointer to include the new updates. so in the case if the total failed you could add a rollback.